# ¿Por qué mi addEventListener no funciona?

Tags: javascript, click, funcion

Soy un "programador" principiante y estoy intentando hacer funcionar un código que he simplificado para que se entienda de mejor manera. Si alguien puede ayudarme con esto lo agradecería mucho ya que no logro entender porqué no funciona. El código es el siguiente:

```js
let boton = document.getElementById('boton');

    function mensaje(){
     console.log('Este es el mensaje');
    }



    boton.addEventListener('click', mensaje);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mostrar mensaje</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3151931480.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <button class="boton" id="boton">mensaje</button>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Y si tienes abierto el developer tools?.

Comment: Por que dices que no funciona, te aparece algun error? Al ejecutar el codigo compartes, funciona bien. `console.log()` solo imprime texto en los dev tools. Intenta usar `alert()` y veras que tu codigo funciona bien.

Comment: Esto funciona. Por qué dices que no?

Comment: Chequea en inspección, consola.. En principio parecería estar todo bien, suponiendo que el script este en el mismo nivel o ruta que el html... Si es así asegúrate de que el nombre sea correcto, a nivel de código estaría ok, después los script generalmente se ponen dentro del body, justo antes de la etiqueta de cierre, pero depende del órden que desees.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado, y cuál es el obtenido?

Answer (score 0):

El script está bien.

Lo que tienes es el típico problema del lugar en que colocas el script. Sucede que el HTML se lee línea a línea de principio a fin.

Al ubicar el script dentro del head, el body aún no está cargado y por lo tanto cuando se ejecuta no encuentra el elemento indicado.

Es recomendable que los scripts que necesiten interactuar con el body se sitúen al final, antes de cerrar el body.

```
<body>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```